# Adding background color to Xamarin Forms WebView has no impact

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.webview

Page markup

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="false" xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="ConnectedLifeView.NativeApp.Pages.LoginSuccessPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="0" Padding="0">
            <WebView x:Name="webView" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="#02114D"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Output
[image: Xamarin Forms WebView]

I tried adding background color to content page and setting WebView background color to Transparent but it has no effect either.

My all other pages have proper background but this page looks a bit weird as it shows white background while the URL loads in WebView.

Xamarin.Forms version: 4.2.0.815419

Platform: Android

Comment: load a static HTML string with the appropriate background color

Comment: Adding static HTML didn't work as the WebView gets blank as soon as it tries to load a URL

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change webview background color, another way is to use custom render.

```
public class TransparentWebViewRenderer:WebViewRenderer

{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<WebView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        // Setting the background as transparent
        this.Control.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.AliceBlue);
    }

}
```

Comment: I was able to achieve the desired result by using custom renderer, but I am still wondering what is the use of having BackgroundColor on the element if it has no effect?

Comment: @Vikram,I guess that it is the design issue, you can create discussion at github. If my reply resolved your issue, please remember to mark my reply as answer.thanks.

Comment: Your answer partially solved my issue. I observed other issues with Xamarin Forms WebView and this link helped me the most http://lukealderton.com/blog/posts/2016/may/autocustom-height-on-xamarin-forms-webview-for-android-and-ios/