# How to change webview background black colour to white colour in xamarin forms

Tags: macos, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

I have a web view to show the browser url image. "My Question is" How to change webview background black colour to white colour in xamarin forms. Please give the solution to resolve this issue

Answer (score 1):

Webview has a *BackgroundColor* property. Set it to White.

```
<WebView BackgroundColor="White"/>
```

Comment: Hi Chris Tina, It's not working. Here is the url (http://www.clobas.com/R3Images/Galleries/502/688/4.jpg), Please check and let me know

Comment: I think webview is the part where the image is displayed and the black background is due to some other layout around it. Do you have any other layouts wrapped around it? Need some code snippet to analyze the issue.

Comment: <controls:CarouselViewControl ItemsSource="{Binding ListPhotoGallery}">
                <controls:CarouselViewControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                         <local:MyWebView   Source="{Binding icon.Uri}"
                                         BackgroundColor="White" />     
                    </DataTemplate>
                </controls:CarouselViewControl.ItemTemplate>
            </controls:CarouselViewControl>

Comment: Chris Tina, You have any Idea?

Comment: Seems like you have created a custom carousel control. Check if it has a background color property and try setting it to white.

Comment: No, i am using CarouselView.FormsPlugin NuGet Package

Comment: Did you check my url where i posted above, if you check then you can able see background colour black(WebView)

Comment: If you just have to display images in the carousel view, try using <Image> and bind it's _Source_ property. See if the problem still persists.

Comment: I like to implement zoom in/out functionality the image using a carousel view, Pan Gesture and Pinch Gesture not flexible that is why I am using a carousel view inside Webview. one more thing I do want Webview load image center Xamarin iOS. Give me a suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I think you could need to use **custom render** to change webview background.

Here is the same thread, you can take a look:

[Adding background color to Xamarin Forms WebView has no impact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58046437/adding-background-color-to-xamarin-forms-webview-has-no-impact)

Comment: Hi Cherry Bu - MSFT, Even I tried Custom Render but it is not help you out. Here is the url (http://www.clobas.com/R3Images/Galleries/502/688/4.jpg), Please check and let me know

Comment: @P.Thiyagu,I try your link, the webview firstly display the correct backgroundcolor, and it will display your link background color when loaded, so I guess that the page you need to load is not transparent, so it covers the webview background color, you can use the link to verify: https://www.google.com/

Comment: I tried your solution but the problem still persist

Comment: Still I am looking for solution, Please give me a solution to resolve this issue

Comment: @P.Thiyagu, I don't have a solution yet, but I try to get the HTML of the web page and change html body background color.

Comment: Bu, Did you find the solution?

Comment: @P.Thiyagu, no,I don't find one solution, do you find a way to do this?

Comment: No Cherry Bu, Still I am looking for solution.

Comment: @P.Thiyagu, If you find a way to do this, please sharing your solution here, thanks.